# can someone help me to turn this sql string in to C# sql query string and get data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
select 
  tsk.Emp_id,
  tsk.ProjectName,
  tsk.Task_description,
  pr.Tasks,   
  pr.Status
from dbo.Tasks tsk
join dbo.Project pr 
  ON pr.Task_ID=tsk.Task_ID
where Emp_id = @emp_id
```

i need to convert this in to c# query string can someone help me to do this , this is not working

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Remove the unrelated tag.)

Comment: What are you using to connect to your database; are you looking for a `linq` query?

Comment: What is a "C# SQL query string", exactly?

Comment: It's already a string. What exactly do you want to convert?

Comment: You might try to find a tutorial on the basics of querying with c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select tsk.Emp_id, tsk.ProjectName, tsk.Task_description, pr.Tasks, pr.Status from dbo.Tasks tsk join dbo.Project pr ON pr.Task_ID=tsk.Task_ID where Emp_id = @emp_id", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", emp_id);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Process the result set
                Console.WriteLine(reader["Emp_id"] + " " + reader["ProjectName"] + " " + reader["Task_description"] + " " + reader["Tasks"] + " " + reader["Status"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```